# Access ViewBag in cshtml file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, window, viewbag

I can't access the values given to windows
,the values given to it are not defined in the js file

this is controller:

```
      ViewBag.CurrentRef_ID = Ref_ID;

     ViewBag.CurrentTas_ID = Tas_ID;
return view(model)
```

this is  Cshtml:

```
@section Scripts
    {
<script>
    window.CurrentRef_ID =@ViewBag.CurrentRef_ID;
    window.CurrentTas_ID =@ViewBag.CurrentTas_ID;

</script>
}
```

and this is js :

```
app.controller("RequestJobsCtrl", ["$scope", "$timeout", "RequestJobsServices", function ($scope, $timeout, services) {

    var self = this;
 self.CurrentRef_ID = window.CurrentRef_ID;

    self.CurrentTas_ID = window.CurrentTas_ID;
```

that in js file value of window.CurrentRef_ID and window.CurrentTas_ID is **undefined**

Comment: The latter JS is probably running before the values are actually set with the previous JS. However, since this is all out of context, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Failed to reproduce the issue ,and I got the value `window.CurrentRef_ID ` and 
 `window.CurrentTas_ID` successfully . What is the definition of RequestJobsServices? Could you share more  details of the view and js file that can reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the value in a hidden div -

View:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="RefValueId" data-id=@ViewBag.CurrentRef_ID> </div>
<div style="display: none;" id="TasValueId" data-id=@ViewBag.CurrentTas_ID> </div>
```

JS:

```
var RefId = $("#RefValueId").data("id");
var TasId = $("#TasValueId").data("id");
```